# Eclipse 4 themes

Tags: css, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am migrating a 3.x eclipse RCP to e4.

I was able to successfully use eclipse's predefined themes. But I have done it by adding an extension to `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme` and copying all the css and images folder found in `org.eclipse.ui.themes` to my application.

I am not going to ever modify those themes I copied. So I was wondering if I can use the themes directly without copying the already made `css` files and `images` folder. This is also not future proof, if I ever upgrade eclipse platform where there was an update in the themes I would have to recopy the new theme resources.

What is the right way to do things? What is the e4 way?

Based on `greg-449` answer I have added the following:

```
<property
           name="applicationCSS"
           value="platform:/plugin/com.example.rcp4/css/default.css">
</property>
```

Where default.css contains:

```
@import url("platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.themes/css/e4_default_win7.css");
```

This works just fine. But now I am facing this look:

[image: e4 styling]

Comment: What in that picture makes you think images are not working? Colors being wroing are generally problems with CSS classes and ids

Comment: @greg-449 I was just going to change my edit. My words were incorrect about the images not working. I will start using the spies to check out what is wrong. But this looks so off.

Comment: @greg-449 checking the css spy the class names seem to be correct. The color definitions however are different. I can't figure out where is it coming from. `e4_default_win7.css` imports `e4_basestyle.css` and that's it. Some colors are not defined in both of these and I find them in the css spy. So weird. Now I am wondering where does eclipse styling come from? Does eclipse use the same css I am looking at (the ones defined in `org.eclipse.ui.themes`)?

Comment: Yes Eclipse uses those themes. I believe some colors come from the Eclipse preferences, these won't work in a pure e4 app which doesn't include that code.

Comment: @greg-449 interesting. Is there a way to grab those preferences set by eclipse?

Comment: I doubt it for pure e4, but I have not looked at this in detail.

Comment: @greg-449 So, I have messed around with the css and I got to know what was causing this issue. It was that all the `ColorDefinition` found in the css are not working. I have copied the complete `e4_default_win7.css` to my `default.css` and it stayed the same until I have replaced all the uses of the `ColorDefinition` with the color codes itself. Is this a bug in `e4`?

Comment: I think ColorDefinition is something that is only available in 3.x compatibility mode- it is what gets the color from the preferences. It probably isn't possible to use themes using this in pure e4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import existing CSS files in to your CSS using `@import` so you don't need to copy them.

Something like:

```css
@import url("platform:/plugin/greg.music.e4.rcp/css/helvneue.css");
```

In this `platform:/plugin/greg.music.e4.rcp` is selecting the plugin containing the css (a plugin with id `greg.music.e4.rcp` in this case). `/css/helvneue.css` is the path to the CSS within the plugin.

Comment: Your answer seems to work fine. I am however facing a weird look of eclipse now. I believe this is due to the images folder not being accessible. Please check my updated question?